# ¿Cómo puedo agrupar estos resultados en un solo select?

Tags: mysql

Quiero armar un select que me permita ver el nombre del insumo con la cantidad que fue comprada...he estado probando bastante y no logro hacerlo, si alguien puede ayudarme con esto, lo agradeceria mucho. Por lo pronto lo que pude logra con este query:

```
SELECT 
    ci.cantidad, 
    ci.id_proveedor_insumo, 
    pi.id_proveedor_insumo, 
    pi.id_insumo, 
    i.id_insumo, 
    i.nombre 
FROM compra_insumos ci 
    INNER JOIN proveedor_insumos pi ON pi.id_proveedor_insumo = ci.id_proveedor_insumo 
    INNER JOIN insumos i ON i.id_insumo = pi.id_insumo
```

Y logre obtener ésto; sin embargo como verán hay muchos registros repetidos, ¿tengo alguna manera de mostrar únicamente el nombre de insumos con su cantidad?

Adjunto resultado de mi query:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto tambien el contenido de las 3 tablas, o si depronto alguien se da cuenta que en realidad solo necesito 2 pues gracias.

Sin embargo, es un poco rara para mi comprender la relación de estas tablas, pero aqui las paso para que puedan ver.

tabla: compra_insumos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla: proveedor_insumos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla: insumos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me interesa poder obtener es la cantidad comprada, y el nombre basicamente. Solo eso, por si acaso es una bd en mysql.

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para mostrar el `nombre` y una suma de las cantidades, basta con que uses **[`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)** con **[`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)**. El uso de ambas permitirá que se sumen todas las cantidades que haya en cada grupo diferenciado por la columna `id_insumo`.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    i.nombre,
    SUM(ci.cantidad) total 
FROM compra_insumos ci 
    INNER JOIN proveedor_insumos pi ON pi.id_proveedor_insumo = ci.id_proveedor_insumo 
    INNER JOIN insumos i ON i.id_insumo = pi.id_insumo
GROUP BY i.id_insumo
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciono perfecto :D